# Tensorflow: Normalizing unbounded data

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, normalization, sigmoid

Normally when people normalize a data set, they tend to do something like:

[Normalize Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvniS.png%27)

My problem with using this technique though, is that my data is not bounded and I really want to avoid imposing an artificial upper or lower bound to my data.

So instead I was considering to use sigmoid or softmax function to normalize my data instead. My data has a shape of (None, 512, 256, 3), and I want a softmax function of the form bellow with gain \alpha and centre \mu:

[Sigmoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D127f.png)

I want the values of \alpha and \mu to be trainable parameters within the model, and have different values of \alpha and \mu for each of the last axis of the input data (3 layers in last axis means 3 trainable \alpha values and 3 trainable \mu values)

How do I go about achieve such a trainable preprocessing step in tensorflow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.